# How to Combine X Number of HTTP Call Responses in Angular?

Tags: http, promise, observable, angular8

I am making a call into a WCF Service that only returns a set amount of data per call. I need to get all of the data before loading the view. However, I do not know how much data there is or how many HTTP calls it will take before I have it all. How can I utilize any needed combination of async/await, observables or promises in order to get this to work properly?

I currently have one function that is supposed to return an Observable to the view and calls the second recursive function. The second function just continues calling the http get function until there is no more data to be retrieved and combines it all into a single array of data. The issue I am having is getting that combined array sent back to the first function to then be sent to the view and retrieved in the subscribe.

```
async retrieveGeographicRegions(iclassType: string) 
{
    let item: DataItem = 
    {
      classType: iclassType,
      TimeStamp: MIN_DATE
    }

    var geographicRegions: Observable<DataItem>;
    var data: any[] = [];
    let index = 1;

    await this.getNextGroupOfRegions(data, item, 1).then((item: DataItem) => 
    {
      //This gets hit before the HTTP call ever finishes for the first time.
      geographicRegions = of(item);
    });
    return geographicRegions;
}

async getNextGroupOfRegions(data: any[], item: DataItem, index: number): Promise<any> 
{
    let timestamp = null;
    let self = this;
    await this.metadataService.ListGeographicRegions(item, index)
    .subscribe(async (items: DataItem): Promise<any> => 
    {
      timestamp = items.TimeStamp;
      items.Data.forEach((item) => { data.push(item);})
      if (items.Data.length == 100) 
      {
        index += 100;
        return self.getNextGroupOfRegions(data, item, index);
      }
      else 
      {
        //Has all of the data from the calls correctly. 
        let newItem: DataItem = 
        {
          classType: "GeographicRegions",
          TimeStamp: timestamp,
          Data: data
        }
        return newItem;
      }
    });
}
```

The expected result is that the view would recieve a DataItem which is just a container of a string, a date and an array of data after it has been populated with All possible data. Currently everything is just undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another hour of thinking on it I figured out a solution. I created a subject in the first function and returned that to the view as an observable. Then passed the subject to the second function. Once all of the data had been retrieved, I cached the data to local storage and called next on the subject so the view recieved all of the data.

```
public retrieveGeographicRegions(iclassType: string): Observable<DataItem> 
{
    var geographicRegions = new Subject<DataItem>();

    let item: DataItem = {
      classType: iclassType,
      TimeStamp: MIN_DATE
    }

    var data: any[] = [];
    let index = 1;

    this.getNextGroupOfRegions(geographicRegions, data, item, 1);

    return geographicRegions.asObservable();
}

async getNextGroupOfRegions(subject: Subject<DataItem>, data: any[], item: DataItem, index: number): Promise<any> 
{
    let timestamp = null;
    let self = this;
    await this.metadataService.ListGeographicRegions(item, index).subscribe(async (items: DataItem): Promise<any> => {
      timestamp = items.TimeStamp;
      items.Data.forEach((item) => { data.push(item);})
      if (items.Data.length == 100) {
        index += 100;
        return self.getNextGroupOfRegions(subject, data, item, index);
      }
      else {
        let newItem: DataItem = {
          classType: "GeographicRegions",
          TimeStamp: timestamp,
          Data: data
        }
        this.storeOnLocalStorage(newItem);
        subject.next(newItem);
      }
    });
}
```